# Missing Features and Existing Lists

Tags: wss-3.0, feature, project-server

I have a site that was hosted on a Microsoft Project Server instance. One of the sub-sites was based on the Project Workspace Template in order to get access to the "special" lists like Risks and Issues.

I am doing some development against the sub-site and as part of my development environment I copied the content database to a new system that **just has WSS installed** (not Project Server). And this is where my problem (question) starts.

I notice that the Issues, Risks, and Deliverables lists throws an "unexpected error has occurred" when I try to view any of the lists. And when I use the API to loop through all the fields in all the lists on the site, the app throws an exception when I get to those lists. The exception I get is the following

```
Feature 'd8d8df90-7b1f-49c1-b170-6f46a94f8c3c' for list template '1104' is not installed in this farm.
```

I can understand the rendering problem if the page was looking for a specific web-part that was installed as part of the feature but why the issues with just looking up fields? I would have thought that when features with column definitions (and lists based on those) were installed and instantiated the definitions would be in the content database?

Any thoughts?